# Configure Multiple Firebase Projects Runtime in iOS application and Firebase/Google Analytics

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

We are starting to migrate from Google Analytics to Firebase Analytics as it is going to be deprecated in a year. We have a need of initializing the firebase project runtime in our iOS application and we are following the steps mentioned here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects?authuser=0

Why do we need to initialize the firebase manually and at runtime? The details are in this issue: [Switching between different firebase projects (runtime) in one single APK file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522034/switching-between-different-firebase-projects-runtime-in-one-single-apk-file)

I posted that issue when we encountered a similar problem for push notifications on Android because at that time the documentation was not sufficient. It is really good to know that firebase documentation has been updated to reflect how to manually initialize the sdk for various platforms.

**Problem:** The problem that we are facing today is that once we initialize the SDK manually for say a "secondary" application and we try to use the firebase analytics, it fails with following error:

```
2018-12-20 17:14:33.526757-0800 App Name[9218:675367] 5.2.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS025018] Event not logged. Call +[FIRApp configure]: AppLaunch
```

Below is the sample piece of code:

```
FIROptions *firoptions = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithGoogleAppID:@"Actual_GoogleAppId" GCMSenderID:@"Actual_GCMSenderId"];
firoptions.bundleID = @"actual.bundle.id";
firoptions.APIKey = @"actual-api-key";
firoptions.clientID = @"actual.client.id";
firoptions.databaseURL = @"https://actual.url";
firoptions.storageBucket = @"actualapp.appspot.com";

[FIRApp configureWithName:@"testApp" options:firoptions];

if ([FIRApp appNamed:@"testApp"]) {
    [FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:@"AppLaunch" parameters:nil];
}
```

Looking at the error it tells us to use [FIRApp configure] which configures the default application from the GoogleService-Info.plist in the project. But we **do not** have GoogleService-Info.plist in our project as suggested  in https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects?authuser=0.

**TL;DR:** We are initializing the firebase app manually in our iOS application using the API [FIRApp configureWithName:@"testApp" options:firoptions]; and the Firebase Analytics gives an error asking us to use default [FIRApp configure] which defeats the purpose of manual initialization.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Firebase Analytics requires the file to be named `GoogleService-Info.plist`. Note the first paragraph of https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects?authuser=0 recommends differentiating multiple versions of it by putting them in different directories.

More details about FirebaseAnalytics and multiple plist files at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/230

Comment: I dont think this is a correct answer and it doesn't help. Look at the last section named "Ensure reliable reporting for Analytics", https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects?authuser=0 and it mentions that we should not add GoogleService-Info.plist to the project. The above issue also mentions the same thing that Google Analytics does NOT work with multiple plist files. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  We've started working with the docs team to make them clearer.

Comment: So does it mean that we need to wait for issue 230 to be fixed before we can use google analytics and Firebase runtime initialization?