# Firebase: What happens when we call delete app on FIRApp defaultApp

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

We are integrating Firebase Analytics into our application as we are moving away from Google Analytics to Firebase Analytics. We initialize the FIRApp instance when user logs into the application and we want to delete the FIRApp instance when user logs out of the application. We are doing this because in our application user can switch environments (Production/Staging/QA) etc. We do not want to capture Production Analytics when they login to Staging. So we only initialize the default FIRApp instance when we detect that user logs into the Production Environment and delete the default FIRApp when they logout. We are assuming that once the default FIRApp is deleted, the tracking should stop. But when we look at the analytics, it seems to capture the screens even when the user has deleted the FIRApp instance. I haven't seen events being captured, but screens are being capture when I delete the FIRApp instance while the app is still running. I can see the screen_views being reported in debug view.

**Below are some more details:**

- **Environment:** iOS (and possibly android)
- **To initialize default app:** `[FIRApp configure];`
- **To delete the default app:** `[FIRApp defaultApp] deleteApp:^(BOOL success) { }];`

**Why are we doing fancy things?** Please see history below:

- [Configure Multiple Firebase Projects Runtime in iOS application and Firebase/Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53878190/configure-multiple-firebase-projects-runtime-in-ios-application-and-firebase-goo/53887107#53887107)
- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/230

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because bug reports about Firebase SDKs should be sent directly to Firebase support. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson I am asking what should be the behavior after we delete the app. I am not saying its a bug. From your comment it seems that it is a bug. Do you agree that after deleting the app, no events should be sent? If you agree that it is a bug, I will open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say what the behavior should be.  Please open an issue.